# Question on Two servo project activated by timer and water level sensor

Tags: arduino

I am using a arduino uno in an attempt to power two servos. Servo A should open for a couple seconds every 24 hours OR if button A is pressed. Servo B should open for a couple seconds if the water level sensor reads below 300 OR if button B is pressed. The code below works fine when I only include one servo, but adding the code for servo B ruins everything.

```
 #include <Servo.h>
Servo myservoA;
Servo myservoB;

const int BUTTONA_PIN = 8;
const int BUTTONB_PIN = 6;
const int SERVOA_PIN  = 9;
const int SERVOB_PIN  = 7;

unsigned long dayTimer_ms = 0;
unsigned long autoOpenDelay_ms = 86400000;

int angle = 0; 
int waterSensor = A0;
int waterLevel = 0;

void setup(){
  myservoA.attach(SERVOA_PIN);
  myservoB.attach(SERVOB_PIN);
  pinMode(BUTTONA_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTONB_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  myservoA.write(0);
  myservoB.write(0);
}

void loop() {

  if(millis() - dayTimer_ms > autoOpenDelay_ms)
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
    myservoA.write(180); //(open?)
    delay(8000);
    myservoA.write(0);
  }
  
  if(millis()<dayTimer_ms)//overflow handling (in case this runs for more than 50 days straight)
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
  }
  
  if (!digitalRead(BUTTONA_PIN) && angle != 180)
  {
    angle = 180;
    myservoA.write(angle);
  }

  if (digitalRead(BUTTONA_PIN) && angle != 0)
  {
    angle = 0;
    myservoA.write(angle);
  }

  if (!digitalRead(BUTTONB_PIN) && angle != 180)
  {
    angle = 180;
    myservoB.write(angle);
  }

  if (digitalRead(BUTTONB_PIN) && angle != 0)
  {
    angle = 0;
    myservoB.write(angle);
  }
 
  int waterLevel = analogRead(waterSensor);

  if (waterLevel <= 300){
    myservoB.write(180);
    delay(8000);
    myservoB.write(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any luck with the proposed solution?

Comment: Unfortunately it only works when I remove the bottom code with the waterSensor. int waterLevel = analogRead(waterSensor);

  if (waterLevel <= 300){
    myservoB.write(180);
    delay(8000);
    myservoB.write(0);
  }. Any ideas?

Comment: do I need "if else"?

Comment: tried "else if" and it still isn't working :/

Comment: Updated answer, lmk if it works

Comment: Could you post a picture of your circuit diagram and the partnumber or a link to your water level sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually super close!

You just need to make a second variable to track angleA separately from angleB.  So you should initialize another variable at the top "angleB" to zero and then replace "angle" with this new variable everywhere below line 52

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservoA;
Servo myservoB;

const int BUTTONA_PIN = 8;
const int BUTTONB_PIN = 6;
const int SERVOA_PIN  = 9;
const int SERVOB_PIN  = 7;

unsigned long dayTimer_ms = 0;
unsigned long autoOpenDelay_ms = 86400000;

int angleA = 0; 
int angleB = 0; 

int waterSensor = A0;
int waterLevel = 0;

void setup(){
  myservoA.attach(SERVOA_PIN);
  myservoB.attach(SERVOB_PIN);
  pinMode(BUTTONA_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTONB_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  myservoA.write(0);
  myservoB.write(0);
}

void loop() {

  if(millis() - dayTimer_ms > autoOpenDelay_ms)
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
    myservoA.write(180); //(open?)
    delay(8000);
    myservoA.write(0);
    angleA = 0; 
  }
  
  if(millis()<dayTimer_ms)//overflow handling (in case this runs for more than 50 days straight)
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
  }
  
  if (!digitalRead(BUTTONA_PIN) && angleA != 180)
  {
    angleA = 180;
    myservoA.write(angleA);
  }

  if (digitalRead(BUTTONA_PIN) && angleA != 0)
  {
    angleA = 0;
    myservoA.write(angleA);
  }

  if (!digitalRead(BUTTONB_PIN) && angleB != 180)
  {
    angleB = 180;
    myservoB.write(angleB);
  }

  if (digitalRead(BUTTONB_PIN) && angleB != 0)
  {
    angleB = 0;
    myservoB.write(angleB);
  }

 
  int waterLevel = analogRead(waterSensor);
  if (waterLevel > 300 && angleB != 0)
  {
    myservoB.write(0);
    angleB = 0;
  }
  else if (waterLevel < 200 && angleB != 180){
    myservoB.write(180);
    angleB = 180;
  }
}
```

the bottom two levels may need to be adjusted (200 and 300).  Basically this creates a slight de-bounce.  By separating the levels at which the water turns on and turns off, it keeps the system from jittering right at the limit (constantly turning on and off).  That being said, depending on the accuracy of your sensor and how important precise level control is in your application, you may want to tighten or move these values around a bit.

Comment: No go unfortunately. Neither button works when the last if command is included

Comment: Do both work fine when the water sensor stuff is commented out?  Perhaps your water level value (300) is not right

Comment: Yes both work fine without it. I tested the water sensor with the serial monitor. For positive if it is not in the water it would be less than 300. However, I don't believe it sends any signal if it doesn't detect any water so maybe I need to add something telling it to open if there is no water level read?

Comment: when you say "doesn't send any signal" what do you mean?  what value does analogRead produce in the following cases: (no water, low water, high water), ballpark values are fine

Comment: Yes so when you turn it on with no water or take it out of the water the serial monitor is blank. 1/3 submerged you get around 300-150 and full 380-450. So when there is no water it does read as 0, it's just not reading.

Comment: Can you post your code for testing the water sensor.  I am confused as a reading of zero should still generate serial prints (and analogRead afaik cannot just not read when called)

Comment: `int adc_id = A0;
int HistoryValue = 0;
char printBuffer[128];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int value = analogRead(adc_id); // get adc value

    if(((HistoryValue>=value) && ((HistoryValue - value) > 10)) || ((HistoryValue<value) && ((value - HistoryValue) > 10)))
    {
      sprintf(printBuffer,"ADC%d level is %d\n",adc_id, value);
      Serial.print(printBuffer);
      HistoryValue = value;
    }
}`

Comment: I think I see now why the serial monitor doesn't show 0 readings

Comment: updated the code to remove the delay on the water actuation and added a de-bounce threshhold.

Comment: Well the new version allows servo A to work perfectly but so far I just get a jumping B servo no matter the water level. Tried adjusting the levels and no difference. I am using a DGZZI Water Level Sensor Module.  Do you have a cash app or Paypal so I can at least donate for your help?

Comment: Could you print "waterLevel " to serial out and let me know what it is reading?  (lmao, happy to help)

Comment: ADC14 level is 25
ADC14 level is 36
ADC14 level is 47
ADC14 level is 34
ADC14 level is 81
ADC14 level is 108
ADC14 level is 119
ADC14 level is 107
ADC14 level is 128
ADC14 level is 140
ADC14 level is 154
ADC14 level is 175
ADC14 level is 195
ADC14 level is 206
ADC14 level is 217
ADC14 level is 228
ADC14 level is 239
ADC14 level is 250
ADC14 level is 239
ADC14 level is 228
ADC14 level is 217
ADC14 level is 206
ADC14 level is 217
ADC14 level is 206
ADC14 level is 217

Comment: Max i saw this time was 230. I guess it depends on water quality. But, again nothing showed on the serial out until I put the censor in the water

Comment: I am actually going to make a change after reading this and plugging into digital pin. https://lastminuteengineers.com/water-level-sensor-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: I am going to abandon the water censor and just put servoB on the same timer. Thanks for trying to help. I learned something again. I will definitely have more questions to bother you with soon though